# cargo +nightly error : no such subcommand

Tags: ubuntu, rust, nightly-build

While executing : `cargo +nightly install --git https://github.com/alexcrichton/wasm-gc --force` in Ubuntu 18.04, is throwing

> error: no such subcommand: `+nightly`

My system has following nightly version

> rustc 1.47.0-nightly

```
 cargo 1.47.0-nightly install --git https://github.com/alexcrichton/wasm-gc --force
```

Even, above command throws similar error!

Cmd1 : `rustup toolchain install nightly`

Cmd2 : `rustup update`

Even after running these commands as suggested over communities, error isn't resolved. I'm new to rust & couldn't link cargo to installed nightly via rustup.

**System Details**

cargo version : `1.43.0`

rustup version :  `1.22.1 (b01adbbc3 2020-07-08)`

Cmd 3:

```
which cargo  : /usr/bin/cargo
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `which cargo`? This looks like you might have either Cargo from your package manager, or a manually installed Cargo taking precedence over the rustup `cargo` alias.

Comment: I concur with @justinas, the cargo  version as of right now is 1.45.1 not 1.43.0. Given you're using ubuntu and it does bundle cargo *but not rustup* this is likely a path conflict, rustup is installing cargo (and the rest) in one location, but you're using the distro's cargo from another. In which case you should remove the distro-provided cargo, or at least fix your PATH such that the rustup-installed one takes precedence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`which cargo` printing out `/usr/bin/cargo` indicates that it defaults to Cargo that you installed from your OS's package manager (apt).

Invocations with the toolchain version like `cargo +nightly` are not a feature of Cargo, but rather Rustup. In fact, Rustup's `cargo` is a link to `rustup` that then invokes the "real" cargo stored under `.rustup/toolchains`.

The easiest way to solve this would be to uninstall the Cargo you obtained from Ubuntu repositories:

```
$ apt remove cargo
```

Otherwise, you could try to manipulate your `PATH` such that `/home/<your_username>/.cargo/bin` comes before `/usr/bin`.

If you *do not* have rustup installed yet, you need to install it.

```
$ brew install rustup-init # OSX
$ curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh  # Ubuntu/Debian
```

Then configure rustup, you can set the config to default to start

```
$ rustup-init
```

Finally you can install specific version of rust, for instance nightly

```
$ rustup toolchain install nightly
```

Answer (score 0):

I was on a mac and not using apt so for me I just had to reference the full path for cargo and it worked.

```
$HOME/.cargo/bin/cargo +nightly --git https://github.com/alexcrichton/wasm-gc
```

Hope that helps somone